# "Open Terminal" from Desktop

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.10

"Open Terminal" in my (Gnome) desktop's context menu opens a terminal in `/home/marcus/` not `/home/marcus/Desktop`. How can I <s>fix</s> change that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe when you open terminal from nautilus actually `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal` do that. But when same is done at desktop that extension doesn't work.

Comment: It is designed to work this way. The option "Open terminal" opens the terminal in the current directory. If you are on the desktop (with "Icons on desktop" enabled), you are working in the Desktop folder, hence that is where the terminal opens.

Comment: @vanadium I think the OP's problem is that it _does not_ work the way it is intended, i.e. the terminal opens in `~` when it should have been opened in `~/Desktop`.

Comment: @danzel There's a little difference in options what you get in nautilus and desktop. When in nautilus, option says "Open **in** terminal" while on Desktop (`~/Desktop`) it says "Open Terminal". So, "open terminal" just opens terminal where it is intended to be, i.e. `~`. Moreover I don't see this as a problem but "**a customization**"

Comment: Okay, it's not saying ```Open in terminal```, but that's what I'd like to have. To open in ```$HOME``` I, of course, use Ctrl+Alt+T.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Type the code bellow in your terminal:

```
echo "cd ~/Desktop" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Once that is done, press Ctrl+Alt+T.
Now the terminal opens in ~/Desktop. In this case, we changed your default working directory in ~/.bashrc to ~/Desktop instead of ~.

Use:

```
echo "cd ~" >> ~/.bashrc
```

to restore back to default.

Comment: I think the OP wants the terminal to be opened in the Desktop folder or, more generally, in the folder where she opened the context menu. Also, changing the value of `$HOME` is not a good idea; there are better ways to open a terminal in a different folder.

Comment: Agreed, changing the $HOME value is a bad idea, that is why I suggested further reading on the matter before acting. Concerning better ways to open a terminal in a custom directory, right-clicking inside a directory of your choice and selecting "open in terminal" would do the job. Also the OP says specifically the need is to open Terminal in "Home", not "Desktop".

Comment: I understand the question as follows: ""Open Terminal" in my (Gnome) desktop's context menu opens a terminal in /home/marcus/..." (<-current behaviour) "... not /home/marcus/Desktop" (<- desired behaviour).

Comment: OP changed his question from "fix" to "change", so, right you are sir. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just `cd` into the desktop, i.e. `cd Desktop/`. It only takes a couple of seconds to type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/917199)

Comment: It should let me post in the comments then rather than having to post a comment as an answer. I'm aware it's not a correct answer but it might be some help to someone new reading this who just want's a quick work-around.

Comment: One could define an alias if it’s too much to type…

Comment: One could, if one wanted to or one could just use the name one's mother gave them.